# How to proceed with Roo installation on windows 8?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-roo

I have downloaded **spring-roo-master.zip** from github. 
In order to start Spring Roo project i need to configure Roo in Eclipse workspace, so i gave path to the `/bootstrap/src/main/bin` but it gives `error: that it is missing the bin folder`. how am i suppose to configure it correctly in order to start the Roo Project.

I am novoice when it comes to GitHub and its repositories and i would appreciate if someone can guide me in an easy way through this problem.

Comment: I'd advice you to download a roo release instead of build it your self. http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/#quick-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install binary distribution http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/spring-roo-1.2.5.RELEASE.zip